# Common per-block instructions with __syncthreads

Tags: cuda

I am looking for some advice for parallel implementation of Miller-Rabin primality proving. Let's assume that on input there is some large odd number `n` and `m` parameter, which means how many odd numbers should it search forward (so it's like `n`, `n+2`, `n+4` and so on). I would like to launch kernel as:

```
miller_rabin_kernel<<<m, k>>>(dev_n, ..)
```

where `k` is another startup parameter, for example it's set to 20, but it may be larger. For each thread there are some specific math calculations, however there are also instructions that are common for them (i.e. "block-wide") and these have to executed just before these "thread-wide". As I understand it is possible to set synchronization barrier with __syncthreads, so every thread in block have to wait until all finishes. My idea of such construct is like:

```
__global__ void miller_rabin_kernel(..) {
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        // Calculate t, s, that are common for all threads in current block
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // Perform further calculations with use of t and s
}
```

Are there some better approaches or is it rather common practice ?

Comment: Your method is reasonable.  If the variables t,s, etc. are different for each block, then your approach makes sense.  If t,s, etc. are the same for all blocks, it may be better to pre-compute and just pass them as kernel arguments, or use a templated kernel, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, those t, s variables are different for each block as they depends on n + 2*blockIdx.x value. To be honest of course they could be prepared earlier in some sort of preprocessing stage at host side for each number and transfered into device memory, however I would like to move possible most operations into parallel code. The trick is that I have actually **two levels** of parallelization.

Comment: With a two-level parallelism, would dynamic parallelism help?

Comment: @JackOLantern: It's interesting idea, however I have only access to Fermi architecture devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a reasonable approach, when there are specific quantities to be computed that are different per block.

If you had a large number of blocks, and the calculations for `t` and `s` were reasonably intense, then you could possibly achieve some benefit by having a separate kernel to precompute your `t`, `s` values, using one thread per quantity, but therefore able to use all the threads in the block effectively.  This kernel could more effectively use the device compute capability and memory bandwidth, since all threads are participating.  You could then leave your `t` and `s` quantities in global arrays, which you would access per block:

```
t = t_array[blockIdx.x];
```

After your `t`, `s` setup kernel is complete, you could then call your main kernel approximately as you have shown.

There will be some overhead to call the first kernel, probably a few microseconds.  Again, if the computation of `t` and `s` is intense, the improved efficiency may offset the overhead for a possible benefit.